# VBA to BROWSE & COPY Data from SELECTED DCM File in Excel

Tags: vba, file, import

As you can figure out of the topic, I am struggeling at VBA. I want to build a Code with the function:

- click on a button
- search the DCM file
- select file
- Open the document in my excel

I realised a code, but I always get a debugg "9" at this line:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

If you may help me I would be very happy :) thanks.

***CODE***

```vb
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", _
                                          FileFilter:="DCM_Datei (*.DCM*),*dcm*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A:O").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
                 
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: error code 9 means subscript out of range. Are you sure you have sheet named Tabelle1 on thisworkbook?

Comment: Yes I think so, I have made a ss and add it below

Answer (score 0):

try this i change structure of copy/paste method and declarate variable for main workbook and worksheet // not tested

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File() 
Dim FileToOpen As Variant 
Dim OpenBook As Workbook 
dim wb as workbook, ws as worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
set wb = thisworkbook
set ws = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="DCM_Datei (*.DCM*),*dcm*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A:O").Copy 
    ws.Range("A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    OpenBook.Close False
    set OpenBook  = nothing         

End If

set wb = nothing
set ws = nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @tomasz, but it doesnt run. (error '1004')

Comment: which line cause error? 1004 its application or object definition error

Comment: This line causes an error:
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

Comment: I have done it. It was a general problem. Big thanks to you. Chears!